# How to only break at words in a regex and include .?!-, at the end of the line?

Tags: regex, string, break, point

I got a problem with regex.

I have the following sentences:

> Dear reader,
>
> this is an example text to show my problem with regex The dot at the
> end of the line is not included.
>
> But I want it to be included.
>
> Thanks for your help,
>
> Shibeson.

And I want my regex to break into a new match after either 40 characters or after a line break. Which it already does perfectly.

Now I want it to only include whole words, which also works quite well with **\b**.

My problem is that if a sentence ends with a ".?!,-" or something like an "ßäöü", it just gets ignored and is not in the matches.

My regex so far is the following:

```
/\b.{1,40}\b|\s/g
```

For the sentences above I would like to get the following output:

| Index | Length | Chars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | 0-11 | Dear reader, |
| Match 2 | 11-12 |  |
| Match 3 | 12-13 |  |
| Match 4 | 13-48 | this is an example text to show my |
| Match 5 | 48-66 | problem with regex |
| Match 6 | 66-67 |  |
| Match 7 | 67-105 | The dot at the end of the line is not |
| Match 8 | 105-113 | included |
| Match 9 | 114-115 |  |
| Match 10 | 115-116 |  |
| Match 11 | 116-144 | But I want it to be included. |
| Match 12 | 145-146 |  |
| Match 13 | 146-147 |  |
| Match 15 | 147-167 | Thanks for your help, |
| Match 16 | 168-169 |  |
| Match 17 | 169-170 |  |
| Match 18 | 170-178 | Shibeson. |

Made a regex101 here to showcase my problem:
https://regex101.com/r/Qvahde/1

Any help is appreciated :)

Edit: Problem 1 got solved: https://regex101.com/r/SSExf3/1
Thanks to @Andrej Kesely

Now my second and final problem is that I only want to have a new match on a line break if it is an empty line with a line break in it.

So I want it like this:

| Index | Length | Chars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match 1 | 0-11 | Dear reader, |
| Match 2 | 11-12 |  |
| Match 3 | 13-48 | this is an example text to show my |
| Match 4 | 48-66 | problem with regex |
| Match 5 | 67-105 | The dot at the end of the line is not |
| Match 6 | 105-113 | included |
| Match 7 | 114-115 |  |
| Match 8 | 116-144 | But I want it to be included. |
| Match 9 | 145-146 |  |
| Match 10 | 147-167 | Thanks for your help, |
| Match 11 | 168-169 |  |
| Match 12 | 170-178 | Shibeson. |

Comment: Maybe `.{1,40}(?=[.,!?\s-])|\n` ? https://regex101.com/r/SSExf3/1

Comment: Wow Thank you @AndrejKesely! Is there a way to only match the \n if it is an otherwise empty line? What I mean is that there are 2 empty matches for a line break now when a line break occurs after a sentence and the next line is an empty one with a line break.

Comment: I edited my question above to show what I want to have as a final result :)

Comment: Do you want to match `\n` that is preceded with `\n`? Then use `(?<=\n)\n`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew! Works like a charm and now I know how to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys,

for anyone interested in the solution I got it now thanks to the two comments above (Thank you!).

To include `.?!,-ßäöü` one has to change the regex to:

```
.{1,40}(?=[.,!?\s-])|\n
```

To only match a line break if it is preceded by an `\n`:

```
.{1,40}(?=[.,!?\s-])|(?<=\n)\n
```

Working example right here: https://regex101.com/r/e8lKXp/1